# How do I use the output from a php file in a TemplaVoila FCE?

Tags: php, typo3, templavoila

I am trying to use the output from a php file in a TemplaVoila FCE.
According to the articles, etc, I have found on the subject, I seem to be doing it right. But it does not work.

I have reduced my implementation to a very simple test, and I hope that someone here can tell me what I am doing wrong.

The php code is in fileadmin/php/test.php

The file contains this code:

```
<?php
function getBeechgroveTest($content, $conf)
{
  return 'B';
}
//echo getBeechgroveTest(0,0);
?>
```

In the main template (template module - not TemplaVoila) I have added this line:

```
includeLibs.beechgroveTest = fileadmin/php/test.php
```

I have tried to put it at the root level and inside a PAGE object. Both gave the same result.

If I uncomment the 'echo' line I get a 'B' at the top of my HTML page, so the php must be read at some point.

My FCE has one field of type 'None (TypoScript only)' and contains this code:

```
10 = TEXT
10 {
  value = A
}

20 = USER
20 {
  userFunc = getBeechgroveTest
}

30 = TEXT
30 {
  value = C
}
```

I was expecting the FCE to output 'ABC', but I only get 'AC'.

What am I doing wrong?

I use TYPO3 version 4.5.30 and TemplVoila 1.8.0

Comment: MB it's stupid but try
`20 = USER_INT`
Since we did not use a USER object, but a USER_INT object, this function is executed on every page hit.

Answer (score 0):

It must by problem in cache, try use USER_INT instead USER. If you create this object as USER_INT, it will be rendered non-cached, outside the main page-rendering.

```
20 = USER_INT
20 {
  userFunc = getBeechgroveTest
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I had already tried that, and it gives the same result.